# Why is the Success property always empty?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am using azure log analytics workspaces and are trying to write a simple query to get the exception message when a azure function fails.

This is the query I am using

```
union AppTraces
| union AppExceptions
| union AppRequests
| where AppRoleName has "-NEU"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
//| where Success == "false"
| order by TimeGenerated asc
| project
    Success,
    TimeGenerated,
    AppRoleName,
    message = iff(Message != '', Message, iff(InnermostMessage != '', InnermostMessage, Properties.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])),
    logLevel = Properties.['LogLevel']
| where logLevel != "Information"
```

The problem is that Success property is always empty and I expect it to be either true or false, I am using the Success property in other queries and it works just fine, for example as follows:

```
AppRequests 
| project TimeGenerated, OperationName, Success, ResultCode, DurationMs, AppRoleName
| where AppRoleName has "NEU"
| where OperationName != "MinimumAppVersionHead" and OperationName != "QueueManagerHead"
| where Success != "true"
| order by TimeGenerated desc 
| take 20
```

In the above case the Success where clause works as expected

Why is it not working in the first query?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below workaround it may help , we have tried with a simple query to check whether the success property is working or not. It works successfully using below query in `logs` with true and false.

*As its works with second query it means you have added log analytics workspace for your function app successfully.*

*It seems there is an issue with `""` , `//| where Success == "false"` instead of that try to remove the comment(`//`) and remove `""` and use as below sample format in your query.*

```
requests
| where success == false
| summarize failedCount=sum(itemCount), impactedUsers=dcount(user_Id) by operation_Name
| order by failedCount desc
```

We have tried with different output with success property as yours in the first query and getting no results . And by removing `""` it works at our end.

***Here are the below sample screenshots of output:-***

### [image]
[image]

***OUTPUT OF THE GIVEN QUERY FOR FUNCTION APP FAILURE:***

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- [***MS DOC| View and query your Function app logs***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/how-to/with-web-app/azure-function-resource-group-management/view-query-application-logs)
- [***BLOG| Alerts on Azure Function failures***](https://vincentlauzon.com/2019/11/01/alerts-on-azure-function-failures/)

Comment: I do not think that is the problem, because with it commented out I expected to see all values right since I am not filtering, but the column is just empty so it doesnt matter if I have "" or not since it is commented out anyway